# How to break a chunked in go using net/http?

Tags: http, go

I have an http server with an endpoint that returns lots of data streamed from a db.  The response is chunked (`< Transfer-Encoding: chunked`).  And if I run into an error, like the DB crashing, I can use a panic & curl will warn me of an issue:

```
curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
```

I don't want a panic though - I just want a simple log message.  And if I `recover()` I don't get the error in curl so there's no indication of something breaking.

Is there a way to break an chunked http response without a panic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error you see from curl is because the connection was immediately closed by the http server when it saw the panic. In order to force the connection closed without a `panic`, you will have to hijack it:

```
// inside the http handler
// func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

// to abort an HTTP/1.1 response
if w, ok := w.(http.Hijacker); ok {
    c, _, err := w.Hijack()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("cannot close connection:", err)
        return
    }
    c.Close()
    return
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Go 1.7, hijacking (as proposed in JimB's answer) is probably the best solution.  Unfortunately, it only works in HTTP/1.1 — it will not do anything useful in HTTP/2.

Go 1.8 introduces a new value `ErrAbortHandler`, and the official way of interrupting an HTTP reply mid-stream is `panic(http.ErrAbortHandler)`, which works for both HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2.  This is described in [issue 17790](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/17790).